# Ruby Koans about_methods line 123 object loop

Tags: ruby

Each time I add in the correct code, it gives me the same error due to AboutMethods:0x00000101841a28 number changing each time.  It's like its stuck and I don't know how to get out this loop.  It worked once, then I went on to the next step, but then it triggered an error after that.

I must not be inputting the correct line of code given from the console?

```
def test_calling_private_methods_with_an_explicit_receiver
exception = assert_raise(NoMethodError) do
  self.my_private_method
end
assert_match "private method `my_private_method' called for #<AboutMethods:0x000001008debf8>", exception.message
```

end

The AboutMethods:0x000001008debf8 changes each time, not sure how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AboutMethods:0x...` is the output of the `inspect` method, which usually (and in this case) includes the class name (`AboutMethods`) and the object id (`0x...`). The object id is related to the objects location in memory, so it will change every time.

In my experience, there is very little value to checking the string from an exception (it's brittle). However, if you feel the need, use a regex:

`` assert_match /private method `my_private_method' called for \#\<AboutMethods:.*/ ``

Comment: Thanks!  I don't regexp that well, but gotta get on that stuff.

Comment: Sure thing. Please vote and accept if it helped. Also, a KILLER tool for Ruby regex testing: http://rubular.com/. Hope it helps!

Comment: The koan hints at using a regular expression as it is assert_match, not assert_equal. As for why you should check the error message, it's because when you are checking tests throw certain exceptions it's useful to know you are throwing the exception for the correct reason. It's no good if future code changes result in the same exception being thrown for a different reason and your tests can't detect this.